# HashMap with Overriding hashcode() and equals() is not working in my case

Tags: java

this is first time I am posting problem.

Please help me to solve my problem. 
In this code i am using HasMap to store key-value pairs, here key is String with three SubStrings separated by " " blank space delimiter.

For example,

```
String t1 = new String("A B C");
and stored in HashMap as-

m.put(t1,27);
```

Here, A, B and C are three different Strings. Where different combinations of A,B,C assumed as unique.

```
Like "A B C", "B A C", "C B A" are all treated as equal.
```

I implemented hashCode() and equal() for this,
Below code should print only

```
A B C:61046662
```

But it is not even calling hashCode() or equals(). Please give me some suggestion.

```
public class Test {
public int hashCode(){
    System.out.println("hashcode method called");
    return this.toString().length();    
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("equal method called ");
    int count = 0;
    if(!(obj instanceof String))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;
    count = 0;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(((String)obj).toString(), " ");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        if(this.toString().contains(st.nextToken())){
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return (count == 3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    String t1 = new String("A B C");
    String t2 = new String("B A C");
    String t3 = new String("C B A");

    m.put(t1, 27);
    m.put(t2, 34);
    m.put(t3, 45);

    System.out.println(m.get("A B C"));

    for(Entry e : m.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(((String)e.getKey())+":" +e.getKey().hashCode());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Both are not related to each other. You are not at all using Test class

Answer (score 3):

Your `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods don't come into the picture because the map keys are of type `String`, not of type `Test`. Thus the standard string comparison and hashcode are being used.

You'll need to modify `Test` so that it holds the string, and change `equals()` and `hashCode()` accordingly. You'll then need to change the map to be of type `HashMap<Test,Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.
ok i understand the concept of why it was not working.
now actually What i need is, I have HashMap same as given above.
I need to remove duplicates of "A B C" from entry. what approach should i use.
I thought above would be correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

The hashCode of the key is used to determine the position and uniqueness of the key. You are adding String objects to the map, so the String.hashCode method is used.
Though you have implemented hashCode for your Test class, these are not used.

To solve your problem you would create your own class used as key, with your own hashCode implementation.
Using your example, you would add a property to your Test class which can hold a string, and use the Test class as key in your map.